# window.open not working with form

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am trying to open a new page when the `form` submit is clicked.
This code works good when the `<form></form>` tag is not there. Why? how can I make it work with the form tag there also?

HTML

```
<form name="input">
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something"/>
    ...
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="reload(this)"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
function reload(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do somthing with inputs
    window.open('new_page.html', '_self');
//  window.location.href = 'new_page.html';
}
```

I tried both `window.open('new_page.html', '_self');`, `window.location.href = 'new_page.html';` and also `e.form.preventDefault;`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTFqt/3/)

Comment: You have `window.open()` and `window.location`; are you trying to open a new page to that location, or redirect the current window to that page? Also, your HTML is invalid (an `input` is an empty element, and therefore has no closing tag). Because with corrected HTML it seems to work ([opening in the same window](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UTFqt/2/), or [in a new window](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UTFqt/4/)).

Comment: @DavidThomas, thank you for the markup tips. WIll correct that. What I want is to open a new page in the same windoe. I have both window.open and window location just to be clear I tried both. What I wonder is why this works ok if I remove the form tags and just make a `<button>` instead of form.

Comment: Apart from anything else you're passing an `HTMLInputElement` into your function, and, in your function, you seem to be expecting an event. If you look at the console you'll see the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'preventDefault'`.

Comment: @DavidThomas, saw your fiddle just now. Interesting! Why does it work with event listener and not with inline calling the reload function like here: http://jsfiddle.net/UTFqt/5/

Comment: @DavidThomas, ok! Got it. With ok input markup and preventDefault without `()` it works. (is it jQuery that needs `()` in preventDefault?) Thank you! Care to post an answer?

Comment: If you pass in the `event` then it works as-is: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UTFqt/7/).

Comment: @DavidThomas, also true. Interesting. Thank you. Now I got 2 different ways to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you're not passing in the `event` to the function, you're passing in the `HTMLInputElement` (with the `this` variable), if you pass in the `event` instead (and assuming corrected HTML), with:

```
<form name="input">
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something"/>
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something"/>
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="reload(event)" />
</form>
```

And:

```
function reload(e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    // do somthing with inputs
    window.open('http://example.com/', '_self');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UTFqt/7/)

Then it works as you seem to expect.

However, I'd, personally, prefer not to use in-line event-handling, instead using unobtrusive JavaScript:

```
<form name="input" method="post" action="#">
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something" />
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something" />
    <input id="Answer" name="Answer" value="" placeholder="something" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

With:

```
function reload (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var win = window.open('http://example.com/', '_self');
}

var form = document.getElementsByName('input')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', reload);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UTFqt/8/).